TinyCME Editor as plugin in Apache-Superset
I am trying to create a custom chart as well as a custom layout element.
To create a custom chart as plugin in Superset, I found this URL: https://superset.apache.org/docs/contributing/howtos
However, I wonder if there is a way, any idea how I could make a plugin to create a "Layout Element" and call it "Text TinyCME" and do it with the TinyCME Editor?

Thanks in advance for any idea or advice
Ben
